# Tell what version of zlib python was built with

Tags: python, c, include, zlib, shared-libraries

How can I tell what version of the C library python's zlib module was built with?

Specifically, I want to tell whether it was a new enough version to support ZLIB_RSYNC=1

This is different than the version of the zlib python *module*, but instead the version of the underlying C library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is `zlib.ZLIB_VERSION`:

```
>>> import zlib
>>> zlib.ZLIB_VERSION
'1.2.7'
```

Comment: apparently the RYSNC functionality I want is a contrib patch and has never been merged

Answer (score 1):

Try the command below to see whether the zlib Python package is available and which version it has:

- For Python 2.x:

```
python -c "import zlib; print(zlib.__version__)"
```

- For Python 3.x:

```
python3 -c "import zlib; print(zlib.__version__)"
```

Answer (score 0):

For c(Recommended):

```sh
cat > get_zlib_version.c << EOF
#include<stdio.h>
#include<zlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%s", ZLIB_VERSION);
    return 0;
}
EOF

gcc get_zlib_version.c -o get_zlib_version && ./get_zlib_version
```

For Python 2.x:

```py
# only show zlib version used for building the module, this may be different from the zlib library actually used at runtime
python -c "import zlib; print(zlib.ZLIB_VERSION)"
```

For Python 3.x:

```py
# The version string of the zlib library actually loaded by the interpreter.
python -c "import zlib; print(zlib.ZLIB_RUNTIME_VERSION)"
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html